# operation not permitted while setting new priority for thread

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have created two threads . By default they have a priority of `0` which i can see using 
pthread_getschedparam and then i try to increase their priority to say `2` and `3` respectively . But Whn i try do do so i get an error

```
     error setting priority for T1: (1), Operation not permitted
     error setting priority for T2: (1), Operation not permitted
```

I have used the scheduling policy of `SCHED_RR` for them

```
       int sched = SCHED_RR;
```

and then performed this :-

```
   if (pthread_setschedparam(t1, sched, &t1_param) != 0) 
  {
     std::cout << "error setting priority for T1: (" << errno << "), " << 
     strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }
```

What is the reason why I am not able to modify my threads priority because priority is within limit of `1` to `99` for SCHED_RR.

Comment: What platform/OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: According to the example program in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setschedparam), you need to be root to set the scheduling priority.

Comment: I did sudo -i and became root user and executed the program but it doesnt work for me ...still the same erroe

Answer (score 20, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I'm not an expert at Linux security, and the following advice might compromise or damage your computer.

In recent versions of Linux, there is a resource limit, `RLIMIT_RTPRIO`, which specifies the maximum real-time priority you can use. You can check this from the shell:

```
> ulimit -r
0
```

On my version of Ubuntu (and probably yours too) there's also a hard limit of zero, so you can't simply use `ulimit` or `setrlimit` to raise this. One way to raise the hard limit is to add a line to `/etc/security/limits.conf` like this (replacing `<username>` with your username):

```
<username> hard rtprio 99
```

Then you should be able to use `ulimit` (from the shell) or `setrlimit` (from your program) to set the soft limit to the priority you need; alternatively, you could set that automatically by adding a second line to `limits.conf`, replacing `hard` with `soft`.

```
> ulimit -Hr # show hard limit
99
> ulimit -r
0
> ulimit -Sr 1 # set soft limit
> ulimit -r
1
```

Do be careful running programs with real-time priority; it can kill the system if it starts misbehaving.

Comment: When I run `ulimit -Hr`, the value is still 0 in Ubuntu 16.04. I also tried re-opening the terminal, but no effect.

Comment: I found I had to set `<username> hard rtprio 99` and `<username> soft  rtprio 99` and reboot in order to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3910) for an explanation.

By default, user tasks in Linux have the scheduling policy `SCHED_OTHER`.  In order to change that to a realtime policy (i.e. `SCHED_RR` as you are attempting to do), you need to be root.  You could try running  your program as root to verify this.

(also note this article is a little outdated - Linux 2.2.  You might want to research this to see if the behavior has changed in newer kernels)

Comment: executing program from user id root is also not working . I wrote same program by user id root and executed but it doesnt work it

Comment: Hmm... See "Privileges and resource limits" in the [manpage for sched_setscheduler](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) for a discussion of how the policies changed in the 2.6 kernel.  You might want to examine the current and maximum values for `RLIMIT_RTPRIO` using `getrlimit()` to see if that's hosing you up?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with `SCHED_BATCH`?

Above may not require root permissions

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this call to fail if you are root and work within the rlimits is cgroups, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511261/232485